# user ads specified php

Tags: php, sql

I created a page called userads with php. The page is intended to display the images of ads that a specific user uploaded on the website. I did a test run with two users logins and found out that the userads page actually displays all the images on my server including those uploaded by a different user. I want the  page to display only the ads of the owner of the account(a single user) how can I do that?
I will drop my code. Pls I want someone to kindly suggest how I could modify the code or better still write a better one for me.

```
<?php
// Include the database configuration file
include_once 'dbConfig.php';
include 'text.php';
// Get images from the database
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");


if($query->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
       
        $imageURL = 'uploads/'.$row["file_name"];
       
?>
      <div class="card shift-down" style=" display:inline-flex;
  width:150px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-block-start: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
" >
    <img src="<?php echo $imageURL; ?>" alt="" width="300px" height="300px"/>
    <div class="card-block" style=" background: #efefef;">
    <h5 class="card-title">Name: <?php echo $product; ?></a></h5>
    <h5 class="card-text">Description:  <?php echo $description; ?></h5>
    <h5 class="card-text">Price: &#x20A6;<?php echo $price; ?></h5>
    <h5 class="card-text">Contact:  <?php echo $phone; ?></h5>
    </div>
    </div>
<?php }
}else{ ?>
    <p>No image(s) found...</p>
<?php } ?> 


<?php include("footer.php")?>
```

Comment: Your query right now fetches all images, you'd need a `WHERE` clause to only fetch images by a specific user.

Comment: Presumably the logged in user's ID is stored in the Session once they've authenticated? So use that in a WHERE clause in your SQL to find only those records which relate to that user. (That's assuming of course that the `images` table has a column which stores the ID of the user who uploaded each image.)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a big step which is serving the images using a php file (that will check all the above regarding authenticated user) and outputs the file to be downloaded - instead of directly linking to the image itself.

Here's a sketch of download.php file that I use

```php
$id = My::getRequestVar("id");
$user_id = My::getSessionVar("user_id");
$file = My::getTableRecord('files', [
    'id' => $file_id,
    'user_id' => $user_id,
]);

if (!$file) {
  die("sorry file not available")
}

$original_name = $file["original_name"];
$stored_name = $file["stored_name"];
$path = UPLOADS_FOLDER_WHICH_IS_NOT_WEB_ACCESSIBLE;
if (!file_exists($fullpath)) {
  echo ("We're sorry but the requested file has been removed from our servers.");
} else {
    //Define header information
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$original_name .'"');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
    header('Pragma: public');

    // this line sends to output
    readfile($fullpath);

    die();
}
```

Then on your html of course:

```html
<img src="download.php?id=<?php echo $image_id; ?>" alt="" width="300px" height="300px"/>
```