# how to list all file and folder directory from drive D and download it using php

Tags: php

here my code how can I access to local folder for example driveD-->folder->.pdf file
and download file when clicking except folder

```
<?php




$path    = './';
$files = scandir($path);
$files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'));
foreach($files as $file){
  echo "<a href='$file'>$file</a>"."<br>";
}




 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not so secure to allow to download *directly* from drive D.

The proper way would be to assign `id` to each file in a database table `files` so that `path` of each file is known. Then have some `download.php?id=123` file to do the actual downloading.

See another recent answer of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73543030/3807365) for a sketch of the solution.

In short:
Create a "download.php" file like this:

```
$id = $_REQUEST["id"];

// according to id get from database:
$file = '../image.jpg';   

// then download
header('Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type($file));
readfile($file);
```

and reference it by

```
<img src="download.php?id=123">
```